# Setting entity key in GET action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, ado.net-entity-data-model

I'm aware it's a quite simple question but I'm a newbie to C#, ASP.NET MVC3 and ADO.Net Entity Framework and my friend google didn't help me much...

So, I have two entities : Post and Comments, with a 1-n relation between them.

I would like to post a comment on a post in a simple form with a route giving the post's id.

The GET part (id being the post's id)

```
    //
    // GET: /Blog/Comment/5

    public ActionResult Comment(int id)
    {
        Comment comment = new Comment();
        comment.PostReference.EntityKey = new EntityKey("BlogEntities.Posts", "id", id);

        return View(comment);
    }
```

The POST Part :

```
    //
    // POST: /Blog/Comment/5

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Comment(Comment comment)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Comments.AddObject(comment);

            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View();
    }
```

I took a ride in debugging mode, and it appears the key is set to null when the form is submitted.
If I set the postreference in the HttpPost method, it just works fine, but I don't have any clue about the id at this point.
So, i think it must be set in the GET part...

Or maybe I'm totally going in the wrong direction ?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Is the key in the GET parameters? Is the page submitting as /Blog/Comment/n?

Comment: yes, indeed, just found it out... totally stupid question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said before, totally stupid question...

```
    //
    // POST: /Blog/Comment/5

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Comment(int id, Comment comment)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Comments.AddObject(comment);
            comment.PostReference.EntityKey = new EntityKey("BlogEntities.Posts", "id", id);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View();
    }
```

Putting the id in method's arg, and then setting the reference after the AddObject did the trick...

Hope it'll help some lost birds like me...